# How to disable shipping method on checkout page Magento 2.0.7

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, checkout-page

I want to remove shipping calculation on checkout page. If i disable all shipping methods from configuration > Sales > Shipping Method, then it will not allow me to proceed to payment section. Is there a way to disable shipping calculation from checkout?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you need ship your product to customer? All of your products are virtual or downloadable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cart contains only virtual or downloadable items, you will not have to select any shipping method at checkout but it will also skip the shipping address during checkout and the associated shipping cost.

Removing the shipping address step for normal simple products (without affecting the shipping method or cost) would be much, much more complicated unless you add a Free Shipping option.

Comment: yes. use free shipping and enable one shipping method for checkout